# Can't open LAI file from Copernicus

Tags: raster, r, copernicus, lai

I downloaded the LAI file from Copernicus: “c_gls_LAI_199908200000_GLOBE_VGT_V2.0.2.nc“
I set the wk and recall the library (raster) to create a RasterLayer object in R:

```
> LAI <- raster("c_gls_LAI_199908200000_GLOBE_VGT_V2.0.2.nc")
```

But it returns this type of error:

```
>Error in R_nc4_open: NetCDF: HDF error
Errore in ncdf4::nc_open(filename, readunlim = FALSE, suppress_dimvals = TRUE) : 
  Error in nc_open trying to open file /Users/sarpic/Documents/datandvi/c_gls_LAI_199908200000_GLOBE_VGT_V2.0.2.nc
```

But the wd is well set

Comment: Can you tell us where you got this file from? Just saying "Copernicus" doesn't help - please edit your question and either link to the file, or a list that has the file in it, or tell us the process you did to get to the file.

Comment: Adding the netcdt4 package along with raster should facilitate reading a "nc" file with `raster::raster` or `raster::stack`.